# Mist 0.9 Freeze: Downloading Swarm binary: 78%

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, swarm

I am running a fully synched geth 1.7.1 local node on mainnet (--datadir "G:)
Mist 0.8.10 loads and works fine

However when I close Mist 0.8.10 and try to run Mist 0.9.0 or 0.9.1 it seems to freeze with the message: downloading swarm binary:78%

Any suggestions as to how to overcome this?

Comment: After some hours the message changes to: Ethereum node up to date but the Mist browser/wallet does not open

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, stuck at 78% too, only with 0.9.x releases on just one Win10 machine. Ethereum Wallet works fine. I have a fully sync'd geth working fine too.

In the end to resolve it I:

- Deleted %appdata%\Mist Folder
- Added an exclusion in anti-virus for "%ProgramFiles%\Mist\Mist.exe"
- Added a specific Windows Firewall rule for "%ProgramFiles%\Mist\Mist.exe", allow all.

Finally, it started up instantly.